# Can I display a G Suite User Photo with the just the thumbnailPhotoUrl?

Tags: firebase, google-api, google-cloud-firestore, google-workspace

### Question

Can a web app display a G Suite user's profile image using just the `thumbnailPhotoUrl`, or is it necessary to save and serve the image?

### Context

[This Guide](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_photo) describes how to get the image from the Directory API. But I'm not sure how to move from the `get` request to an image file I can display. There is mention of the [Closure Library](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/gettingstarted) to use for Base64 encoding/decoding.

I'd like to use a **link** to the image, to use as the `src` of an `img` element.

### What I've Tried

A firebase cloud function using a service account with domain-wide delegation is retrieving user data via `https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users`. This returns the `thumbnailPhotoUrl`, and I'm able to paste the URL into chrome and view the image. If I share the `thumbnailPhotoUrl` with someone else, they do not see the image but see the silhouette placeholder instead.

Note: the `thumbnailPhotoUrl` includes `/private` *like* this:

`https://www.google.com/s2/photos/private/xyz123...`

Is that a clue that this URL will not work in the web app to display the image?

Comment: Did it work for you? I tried downloading the image programmatically and it also downloaded the silhouette image. How did you manage the download the thumbnail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed the contents of the URL directly into your HTML document. It looks like this:

```
<img width="16" height="16" alt="star" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7" />
```

The magic part is taking the image binary data and base-64 encoding it for the img tag.

The format of the above example:

```
data:[<mime type>][;charset=<charset>][;base64],<encoded data>
```

This [link](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) provides more details and shows how to do this.